# calculating an integral with green's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let 
$ M:\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_+^{2} : x^2+ 4y^2 \leq 4, 1 \leq x^2-y^2 \} $

I want to use Green's Theorem:

$ I(M)= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\partial M} x_1 dx_2 -x_2 dx_1 $

M is the region where the ellipse and hyperbole are overlapping above the x axis,
so $ \int_{\partial M }$ must be  $ \int_1^2 $ right?

now, I am not sure what to use as function I need to integrate.I could not find any similar examples.
Your help is very apreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean $\displaystyle I( M) =\frac{1}{2}\int _{\partial M} xdy-ydx$

Taking $\displaystyle I( M)$ as written above, by green's theorem this is the area of region M

[image]

Blue shaded region is the Region M.
\begin{gather*}
\therefore Area\ of\ M=I( M) =2\int ^{\frac{3}{5}}_{-\frac{3}{5}}\int ^{2\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}_{^{\sqrt{y^{2} +1}}} dxdy\\
or\ I( M) =\left[ y\sqrt{1-y^{2}} -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{y^{2} +1} +\arcsin( y) -\frac{1}{2}\ arcsinh( y)\right]^{y=\frac{3}{5}}_{y=-\frac{3}{5}}\\
or\ I( M) =\frac{24}{25} -\frac{3\sqrt{34}}{25} +2\arcsin\left(\frac{3}{5}\right) -\ arcsinh\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)\\
or\ I( M) \approx 0.9785
\end{gather*}

Comment: thank you for your answere! Since $ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^+}^2 $ are the bounds not quite right, right? Where does the Green's Theorem flows in ?

Comment: @wondering1123 The formula for area,i.e.,I(M) has been derived from Green's theorem

Comment: I am sorry, but thats the way i would normally integrate it..I thought about it and I still can not explain it with the formular $I(M)$ above.  would you mind explaining it?

Comment: You haven't used Green's theorem to evaluate the area.  If you use Green's theorem, you will evaluate a line integral, not a double integral.

Answer (score 1):

Green's theorem says that $$\int_{\partial S}{Pdx+Qdy}=\int\int_S(Q_y-P_x)dxdy$$ with suitable hypotheses on $P,Q,S$.  So if we set $P(x,y)=0, Q(x,y)=y,$ we see that the area of $S$ is $$\int_{\partial S}{y dy}$$  You simply have to parametrize the curves bounding $S$ and integrate the expression for $ydy$.

$S$ breaks into two congruent regions, so it's enough to compute the area of one of them.[image]

The region on the right is bounded below by a segment the x-axis.  If we parameterize $y$ on this axis, we will have $y=0$ of course, so the line integral will be $0$ and we can ignore it.  The blue boundary curve runs from $(2,0)$ to the red dot at $(\sqrt{1.6},\sqrt{.4})$ and we can parameterize along this curve as $y$ as $$
y=\sqrt{{4-x^2\over4}}\implies dy= {-xdx\over 2\sqrt{4-x^2}},$$ so you have to integrate ${-x\over4}dx$ from $x=2$ to x=$\sqrt{1.6}.$  The direction of the integral is determined because in Green's theorem, the contour of the line integral is oriented counter-clockwise.

We have $ydy={-x\over8}dx,$ so we compute $$\int_2^{\sqrt{.6}}{-x\over8}dx={-x^2\over16}\biggr\rvert_2^{\sqrt{.6}}={3.4\over16}$$

Do the same thing for the arc of the hyperbola that bounds the region on the right.

Comment: thanks for the detailled explanation! It is still quite hard for me to get it..and I need to integrate only for positive $x,y$

Comment: I'll add a few more details.  Wait a bit.

Comment: I added some details.  Note that the contour satisfies $x\ge0, y\ge0$ so we are considering only positive $x$ and $y$.  What makes you think we aren't?